# Integral of the absolute value of sin(x)/x

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that $\int_0^\infty |\frac{\sin(x)}{x}|dx=\infty$.
I thought it would work out by using the power series of the sine
but I'm just not getting the endresult.

Could someone please help me?

Thank You very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** On the interval $[n\pi,(n+1)\pi)$, $\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right| \geq \frac{\sin(x)}{(n+1)\pi}$. What do you get if you integrate $\frac{|\sin(x)|}{(n+1)\pi}$ on $[n\pi,(n+1)\pi)$ and add these up?

Comment: Not quite right.  Note that $\sin(x)$ is negative if $n$ is odd.

Comment: Oops, fixed. Thank you.

Comment: @kccu Thank you very much, that helped a lot! Now I've got that the integral is greater or equal to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2}{(n+1)\pi}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the integral over $[n \pi + \pi/3, n \pi + 2\pi/3]$ is greater than a constant$/(n+1)$.